# Are insurance payouts taxable in Canada?

Tags: canada, income-tax, life-insurance

This is in reference to this question about [life insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/546/how-much-life-insurance-do-i-need) but can apply to other insurance payouts.  This would definitely affect how much to plan for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are an individual purchasing life insurance, then the proceeds are not taxable when paid to the beneficiaries.